# phpmyadmin server name change

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, server, wamp

I am really new in this kind of stuff so my question might be to easy or stupid but please do help this newbie.

When I opened my phpmyadmin, the server was named: mysql wampserver. Usually in tutorials, their server name was localhost. Can you please tell me how to change the name of the server if possible so I can use the tutorial easier if we have the same sever name.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Through wampserver, when enabled just visit `127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` or `localhost/phpmyadmin`

Comment: **phpMyAdmin** is a tool for accessing and maintaining a **MYSQL** database. phpMyAdmin is no a server. Apache is a server, MYSQL is a server.

Answer (score 11):

That name is absolutely irrelevant to anything. It is actually set in this file `wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\config.inc.php` using this parameter

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
```

It effects nothing and if it really bothers you you can amend it to anything you like

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Mackinley Databases on my PC';
```

Answer (score 1):

The WAMP server doesn't maintain a name. You connect to it via an IP address... do you not know the IP of the machine it's installed on?

If it's on your own computer, you can connect to the Sql server from code by connecting to 127.0.0.1:3306 (default port).

If it's not on your machine, find the ip address of the machine it's running on by going to the command prompt and typing 'ipconfig'.

Then use that IP address and port 3306 (or whatever port you defined, 3306 is just default)

Default access will be via localhost or 127.0.0.1. Might not work (rarely) if it was modified before.

Also Check you Host file. make a copy of before editing host file ..